# How do I add an inventory remaining counter?

Tags: python

Previously, I have asked for help in my attempt to add an inventory counter that has not worked. This is the original program I made. Everything works properly. How do I set each item (Pants, Shirt, Dress, Socks, and Sweater) to have a qty of 100 then take the input of qty and subtract that number. Lastly, printing what is left of the 100 after your bill is printed in Option 2 of the menu. Please edit the code to help me solve this issue. I really want to be done with this program. Thank you for your time.

```
#DEFINING EACH RETAIL ITEM TEMPLATE
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self,desc,unit,price):
        self.description = desc
        self.units = unit
        self.price = price

#CREATING WHERE SELECTED ITEMS WITH RESIDE
class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shopping_list=[]
    def purchase_item(self,retail):
        #adding item to list
        self.shopping_list.append(retail)
#CREATING PRICING / COST
    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for i in self.shopping_list:
            total+=(i.units*i.price)
        return total
#HOW THE CHECKOUT WILL FORMAT/LOOK IN AFFECT ON OPTION 2 (CHECKOUT)
    def show_items(self):
        if not self.shopping_list:
            return
        print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format(" "*9,"Description","Units","Price"))
        print("-"*75)
        for c,i in enumerate(self.shopping_list,1):
            print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format("Item #"+str(c),i.description,i.units,i.price))
        print("-"*75)

def main():
    #ADDING TO CART
    c=CashRegister()
    #MENU

while 1:
    try:
        print("1. Purchase\n2. Checkout\n3. Clear\n4. Exit")
        print()
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        print()
        if choice == 1:
            while 1:
                print()
                print("Menu\n-----------------------\n1. Pants\n2. Shirt\n3. Dress\n4. Socks\n5. Sweater")
                item_type = int(input("Select item: "))
                print()
                qty=int(input("Enter quantity: "))
                #ITEMS TO CHOOSE FROM AND ADD TO CART
                if item_type == 1:
                    c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Pants",qty,44.95))
                elif item_type == 2:
                    c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Shirt",qty,34.95))
                elif item_type == 3:
                    c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Dress",qty,79.95))
                elif item_type == 4:
                    c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Socks",qty,6.95))
                elif item_type == 5:
                    c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Sweater",qty,24.95))
                else:
                    #ERROR MESSAGE
                    print("Invalid item! try again")
                    print()
                    continue
                print("Item added to list")
                print()
                break
        elif choice == 2:
            if not c.shopping_list:
                #ERROR MESSAGE
                print("Nothing to checkout!")
                print()
                continue
            #DISPLAYING BILL
            c.show_items()
            print(" "*60+"Total: ${}".format(round(c.get_total(),2)))
            print()
        elif choice == 3:
            #CLEARING
            c.shopping_list=[]
        elif choice == 4:
            #EXIT
            exit()
        else:
            #ERROR MESSAGE
            print("Invalid choice! try again!")
        print()
        #ERROR MESSAGE
    except Exception as e:
        print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
        print()

#RUN PROGRAM
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs, waiting for input.  The code is not minimal.  Please include the entire error message, and make sure that you trace the offending values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never define `item_type_qty`. All you ever do with it in your class is this:

```
self.item_type_qty[["Pants",20],["Dress",20]]
```

Which has no effect, since it looks like you're trying to get a value out using weird indexes. If you meant to assign it, do it like this:

```
self.item_type_qty = [["Pants",20],["Dress",20]]
```

However, you'll run into another problem with this line:

```
for x in c.item_type_qty:
```

That line is run before you call `inhand`, meaning `item_type_qty` will be still undefined when that line is reached, throwing that error anyway. You kind of have a circular dependency going on, where you try to loop through `item_type_qty`, which is set by `inhand()`, but then in your loop you call `inhand()` with `x[0]` and `x[1]`, but `x` is an item from `item_type_qty`, which is defined in `inhand`. Just kind of a messy situation that doesn't make sense.